# Powershell find matching filenames in list and ignore file contents

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to identify all files from text file of paths that match a pattern. `Select-String` is searching the *content* of the files and not just the list of file names. How do I confine it to just the list?

I've read through the docs on [SS64](https://ss64.com/ps/select-string.html) and [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.2) and tried the parameters that look related,`-Raw`, `-SimpleMatch` and `-Path` for instance. No go.

List of names to search through:

```
» $fileList
\\server\imagery\09Aug2015\506000_6717000.tif
\\server\imagery\515000_6896000.tif
```

The results I'm getting:

```
» Select-String -Pattern "Aug" $fileList

\\server\imagery\516000_6895000.tif:8675:�|K`�����aug♦b��k��!���1�]��4hl�
\\server\imagery\516000_6895000.tif:25187:�c;H�S�m�EFyѰ��p9犞��`��!♂5�6"�_���F9�↨��Y�w↑��h�►�,�(↔
���%�]�ֶ�       ↨↕�}zd��Z-������K��E@   �♦��V~�☼�5[kw���Ȩ‼=�����^��|e▲�¶�X�푆NH,��v�∟�[⌂♀x�/☼�s$�[ZF�;g♀�8�k������cǑxz��W���"���3.♠ ~��
�→Ѷ��'��↑�V#���[D�$6�+↑�/�0��W#���q�§�*��u++�♦��▬�v↔☺��uk�u{���I��↓¶aUGLRj������Ġ�
\\server\imagery\\516000_6895000.tif:34275:�t��&R��:�r�@H鑚��+�xg�▲ �.��i�(�‼�\�w‼�.�d��B��ѫ▼��BA�T`
��AuG♦�z{�§�0�X�‼��↑5�Ÿe;↨�X�-��������]�%Ԕ٤�NѸ1�'�?Z���d���!7�ʻ��X�g��kK]�Ӥ�O���♥"�$8;�����⌂Ju�����آ�8U2�3�Ǧ�?�>�
uco"Ɖ�§@��׿�Io¶���ӭ^(�s"♫p♠y�▲�J�{m4w♂n�3�☺Td�ҩ_� �;t♣ߑ����U↔B��9c�|;▬;P`��▲x�<‼�
```

Desired result:

```
» Select-String -Pattern "Aug" $fileList

\\server\imagery\09Aug2015\506000_6717000.tif
```

I'm using Powershell Core v7.2 on Win10.

Comment: What is `$fileList`? Please  share a [mcve]. Maybe `$fileList| Where-Object { $_ -match 'aug' }`?

Comment: @JosefZ the first block shows the contents of the variable. I've removed the slicing parts from my parts. The results I get are the same with this reduced set.

Comment: @JosefZ thanks. `Where-object` does work for me here. I'm still curious about how to instruct `Select-String` to ignore file contents as the syntax is more straightforward. Not so much that I'll continue chasing it down though! Write as answer so I can mark this  solved well enough for present goals.

Comment: If you insist upon `Select-String` then try `$fileList | Select-String -Pattern "Aug" -SimpleMatch`. Note that it results to a `[MatchInfo[]]` object if `$fileList` is a `[String[]]` object… Works in  `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString() -eq '7.1.5'` on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search the literal strings in your variable, you pass it down the pipeline like this.

```
$filelist | Select-String -Pattern aug -AllMatches
```

When you call it like you did, it's binding to the path parameter. It can either search contents of files or strings, depending on what you give it.

```
Select-String -Pattern aug $filelist
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to search the file names.
Get-ChildItem '\server\imagery' -recurse -include *aug* | select-object fullname | sort fullname | more

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion John. This file share is very large so I'm avoiding the expense of real-time search using a listing generated in off hours. It's good to have this approach here for others to think of though.